# highlight feature from feature id in qgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, qgis-processing

i am making a qgis plugin and want to highlight a feature from feature id but the feature id must be taken from the textbox my code is below but this shows error like **cLayer.setSelectedFeatures(me)
            TypeError: expected string or buffer**

```
    inputid = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
    cLayer = self.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
    query = '"ID" = {''}'.format(inputid)
    selection = cLayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
    me = [k.id() for k in selection]
    cLayer.setSelectedFeatures(me)
```

Comment: I believe @mgri is correct in that you will need to select your layer from the _Layers Panel_ to avoid that error. What about using a [QgsMapLayerComboBox](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerComboBox.html) where the user can select from a list of available layers and then call this layer in your code?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that QGIS doesn't recognize the layer.

The line:

```
cLayer = self.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
```

returns a `QgsVectorLayer()` object only if it is currently selected in the Layers Panel. Otherwise, a `None` is returned and the error you encountered.

I don't know the source of the input layer, but a general method for loading it would be:

```
cLayer = QgsVectorLayer('path to the vector layer', 'display name', 'ogr')
```

Comment: thanks now m getting an error like:-          **cLayer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
TypeError: expected string or buffer**

Comment: @vaibhavDhiman, as you read from the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), comments are used to asking for more information or clarify a question or answer. The error you reported is referred to another issue (and you get a new error because the one from your original question was solved), so the best would be accepting my answer (if it helped you to find a solution) and asking a new separate question where you isolate this new specific error.